# How to add two outputs or query and get a one consolidated result for below queries

Tags: oracle

1.

```
select M.MASTER_REF, case B.Type when 450 Then 'RED'                               
when 420 Then 'RVL'                                                 
END Note_Type, B.CODE, B.NOTE_TEXT, (E.REFNO_PFIX || ''|| E.REFNO_SERL)AS Event_Ref, B.CREATED_AT, B.ACTIVE
from Note B, MASTER M, BASEEVENT E, TIDataItem N
where B.KEY97=N.KEY97 and N.MASTER_KEY=M.KEY97 and E.KEY97 = B.NOTE_EVENT
and M.EXEMPLAR in ('8806648499869051681','8806648499869023154','8806648499869054292','8806648499869006425')
and M.STATUS in ('LIV','EXP')
and B.Code not in ('Migration')
order by M.Master_Ref Asc, B.CREATED_AT desc
```

2.

```
select M.MASTER_REF, case B.Type when 450 Then 'RED'
when 420 Then 'RVL'            
END Note_Type, B.CODE, B.NOTE_TEXT, B.Note_Event AS Event_Ref, B.CREATED_AT, B.ACTIVE
from Note B, MASTER M, TIDataItem N
where B.KEY97=N.KEY97 and N.MASTER_KEY=M.KEY97 and B.NOTE_EVENT is null
and M.EXEMPLAR in ('8806648499869051681','8806648499869023154','8806648499869054292','8806648499869006425')
and M.STATUS in ('LIV','EXP')
and B.Code not in ('Migration')
order by M.Master_Ref Asc, B.CREATED_AT desc
```

Comment: Don't tag all database, just the one you are actually using.

Comment: Have you tried `UNION`? Also, which of the three DBMSes you list is the one you're using? or, is this being executed in multiple databases?

Comment: Ezlo I am not a developer but seeking help to learn things.. Was not aware how to tag...sorry for it...I tried what you have suggested getting below error               ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression
01790. 00000 -  "expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 8 Column: 25

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` to add similar result sets together. Column order and data types must match between each set. The `ORDER BY` should be at the last `SELECT` only and can reference only column alias.

```
select 
    M.MASTER_REF, 
    case B.Type 
        when 450 Then 'RED' 
        when 420 Then 'RVL' END Note_Type, 
    B.CODE, 
    B.NOTE_TEXT, 
    (E.REFNO_PFIX || ''|| E.REFNO_SERL) AS Event_Ref, 
    B.CREATED_AT, 
    B.ACTIVE
from 
    Note B, 
    MASTER M, 
    BASEEVENT E, 
    TIDataItem N
where 
    B.KEY97=N.KEY97 and 
    N.MASTER_KEY=M.KEY97 and 
    E.KEY97 = B.NOTE_EVENT and 
    M.EXEMPLAR in ('8806648499869051681','8806648499869023154','8806648499869054292','8806648499869006425') and 
    M.STATUS in ('LIV','EXP') and 
    B.Code not in ('Migration')

UNION ALL

select 
    M.MASTER_REF, 
    case B.Type 
        when 450 Then 'RED'
        when 420 Then 'RVL' END Note_Type, 
    B.CODE, 
    B.NOTE_TEXT, 
    TO_CHAR(B.Note_Event) AS Event_Ref, 
    B.CREATED_AT, 
    B.ACTIVE
from 
    Note B, 
    MASTER M, 
    TIDataItem N
where 
    B.KEY97=N.KEY97 and 
    N.MASTER_KEY=M.KEY97 and 
    B.NOTE_EVENT is null and 
    M.EXEMPLAR in ('8806648499869051681','8806648499869023154','8806648499869054292','8806648499869006425') and 
    M.STATUS in ('LIV','EXP') and 
    B.Code not in ('Migration')
order by 
    Master_Ref Asc, 
    CREATED_AT desc
```

I strongly suggest you avoid using old join syntax as it makes the code less readable (use explicit `INNER` or `LEFT JOIN` with the proper `ON` clause):

Change:

```
from 
    Note B, 
    MASTER M, 
    TIDataItem N
where 
    B.KEY97=N.KEY97 and 
    N.MASTER_KEY=M.KEY97
```

For:

```
FROM
    Note B
    INNER JOIN TIDataItem N ON B.KEY97 = N.KEY97
    INNER JOIN MASTER M ON N.MASTER_KEY = M.KEY97
```

Comment: ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression
01790. 00000 -  "expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 8 Column: 25

Comment: @Mann The expression `(E.REFNO_PFIX || ''|| E.REFNO_SERL)` return type doesn't match with `B.Note_Event` (which is the corresponding column from the other `SELECT`). Try converting the latter to string with `TO_CHAR()` (edited on the answer).

Comment: @Ezlo..I dont know how to thank you ...You have been a great saviour ..I have been trying to fix this small piece of code from last 3 days...I want to salute the help you extended me...wish i could offer u a cup of coffee atleast :)   How can i become an expert like you ...can you refer something to read and study SQL queries

Comment: @Mann you can start with any beginning PLSQL manual, lots of things to learn!